# Classify the main list into substituens using prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm attempting to check if any element of the first list has a match on the second list. If matching found classify that element and split with that element, then we again check the rest of the list. If there are more matches found in particular classification then append the those lists.

I try some classify code below but it didn't correctly work. This order of the format is only work.

```
?- classify_substituens([1,2,ab,hj,de,as,t,pq,js,xy,ac],Ab,De,Pq,Xy,Rest).
Ab = [1, 2, ab],
De = [hj, de],
Pq = [as, t, pq],
Xy = [js, xy],
Rest = [ac].
```

My code:

```
classify_ab(N,Ab,R):-append(B,[ab|R],N),append(B,ab,Ab),!.
classify_de(N,De,R):-append(B,[de|R],N),append(B,de,De),!.
classify_pq(N,Pq,R):-append(B,[pq|R],N),append(B,pq,Pq),!.
classify_xy(N,Xy,R):-append(B,[xy|R],N),append(B,xy,Xy),!.

classify_substituens(List,Ab,De,Pq,Xy,Rest):-
    classify_ab(List,Ab_1,Rest_1),
    classify_de(Rest_1,De_1,Rest_2),
    classify_pq(Rest_2,Pq_1,Rest_3),
    classify_xy(Rest_3,Xy_1,Rest4),
classify_substituens(Rest_4,Ab_2,De_2,Pq_2,Xy2,Rest),
    append(Ab_1,Ab_2,Ab),
    append(De_1,De_2,De),
    append(Pq_1,Pq_2,Pq),
    append(Xy_1,Xy_2,Xy),
    !.
classify_substituens(List,[],[],[],[],List).
```

I want goals like below.

```
?- classify_substituens([1,2,ab,a,b,xy,as,t,xy,ac],Ab,De,Pq,Xy,Rest).
Ab = [1, 2, ab],
De = [],
Pq = [],
Xy = [a,b,xy,as,t,xy],
Rest = [ac].
?- classify_substituens([1,2,ab,a,b,de,s,t,ab,i,ac],Ab,De,Pq,Xy,Rest).
Ab = [1, 2, ab,s,t,ab],
De = [a,b],
Pq = [],
Xy = [],
Rest = [i,ac].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify my life, I'm calling the atoms `ab`, `de`, `pq` and `xy` "endcaps."

```
endcap(ab).
endcap(de).
endcap(pq).
endcap(xy).
```

Your code happens to match this, which I think is simpler:

```
takeUpto(Token, List, PrefixToken, Remainder) :-
    append(Prefix, [Token|Remainder], List),
    append(Prefix, [Token], PrefixToken).

classify_substituens(List, Ab, De, Pq, Xy, Rest) :-
    takeUpto(ab, List, Ab, R0),
    takeUpto(de, R0, De, R1),
    takeUpto(pq, R1, Pq, R2),
    takeUpto(xy, R2, Xy, Rest).
```

This unfortunately still does not work. What you're trying to do is make bins and drop everything into the right bin. I see a way to do it with a single pass but it is fairly gross. I spent about 30 minutes on it and found it too difficult to debug. A verbal sketch would be this: delegate to a helper method with an accumulator, a "rest" variable and with two variables for each bin: one for input, one for output. The helper method has a case for getting an empty list; map the input variables to the output variables and the accumulator to the "rest" variable. Now the helper has a case for each "endcap" and they all look almost the same: append the accumulator to the singleton list of the endcap, and forward that to a recursive call as the new state variable for this endcap. It sounds easy but there are 11 variables involved and a lot of copy/paste.

I did come up with a solution though, which seems (to me) fairly easy to read and write. It is not efficient. Sorry.

First, I want to get the "substituens" of interest. I group them together and then label them with the particular flavor they have.

```
substituens(Acc, [], [], Acc).
substituens(Acc, [X|Xs], Subs, Rem) :-
    (   endcap(X) ->
        append(Acc, [X], Substituen),
        substituens([], Xs, RemainingSubs, Rem),
        append([X-Substituen], RemainingSubs, Subs)
    ;   append(Acc, [X], Acc1),
        substituens(Acc1, Xs, Subs, Rem)
    ).
```

This works like so:

```
?- substituens([], [1,2,ab,a,b,de,s,t,ab,i,ac], Y, Rem).
Y = [ab-[1, 2, ab], de-[a, b, de], ab-[s, t, ab]],
Rem = [i, ac] ;
false.
```

I didn't bother making a `substituens/2` wrapper for this because I'm only going to call it from `classify_substituens/6`. Now I say, suppose I have some endcap category. Let me get all the stuff from this lookup table-like structure

```
condense(Category, Groups, Condensed) :-
    findall(Group, member(Category-Group, Groups), MyGroups),
    append(MyGroups, Condensed).
```

This depends on `append/2`, which is not ISO but probably is not super-hard to write since it's just the fixed-point of `append/3`.

These two helpers make short work of `classify_substituens/6`:

```
classify_substituens(List, Ab, De, Pq, Xy, Rest) :-
    substituens([], List, Subs, Rest),
    condense(ab, Subs, Ab),
    condense(de, Subs, De),
    condense(pq, Subs, Pq),
    condense(xy, Subs, Xy).
```

And there you have it:

```
?- classify_substituens([1,2,ab,a,b,de,s,t,ab,i,ac],Ab,De,Pq,Xy,Rest).
Ab = [1, 2, ab, s, t, ab],
De = [a, b, de],
Pq = Xy, Xy = [],
Rest = [i, ac] ;
false.

?- classify_substituens([1,2,ab,a,b,xy,as,t,xy,ac],Ab,De,Pq,Xy,Rest).
Ab = [1, 2, ab],
De = Pq, Pq = [],
Xy = [a, b, xy, as, t, xy],
Rest = [ac] ;
false.
```

Incidentally, this also shows me that one of your test cases is wrong. :) `De` must always end with `de`.

I do have a lingering sense that there may be an efficient *and* readable way to do this using DCGs or difference lists, but my DCG power is not quite strong enough to see it. Maybe someone else will try it?

So, kudos for a hard problem that makes no sense! This is one of the strangest questions I can recall on [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) in a long time! I really don't see why you would ever want this, but I hope my code helps, even though it is pretty amazingly inefficient.